# Can't create a popover with custom template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

First I tried using angular-ui

```
<span popover-template="removePopover.html" popover-title="Remove?" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove cursor-select"></span>
```

here the template is not included and no errors are provided in console. As I undestood from [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982204/popover-template-in-angular-ui) this capability is still in development (using v0.13.0).

Then I tried using bootstrap's popover

```
<span delete-popover row-index={{$index}} data-placement="left" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove cursor-select"></span>
```

This is included to popover

```
<div id="removePopover" style="display: none">
        <button id="remove" type="button" ng-click="removeElement()" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="cancelElement()" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

This is the managing directive

```
app.directive('deletePopover', function(){
  return{
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).popover({
            html : true,
            container : element,
            content: function() {
                return $('#removePopover').html();
            }
        });
    scope.removeElement = function(){
        console.log("remove"); //does not get here
    }
    scope.cancelElement = function(){
        console.log("cancel"); //does not get here
    }
    }
  };
});
```

In case of bootstrap's popover the scope is messed up. `cancelElement()` call does not arrive in directive neither the parent controller.

If anyone could help me get atleast on of these working it would be great.

Comment: What about ``removeElement()`` call. is it working ?? Just want to know why cant you use ``modal`` which provide better controls of button actions ??

Comment: I don't know where the `removeElement` call is directed. It does not go to the directive and neither to the controller...

Comment: Can you explain functionality that are trying to achieve. ??

Comment: I have a remove button in my table rows. And if the user clicks on that remove I want to create a popover to confirm the removal.

Comment: In that case i would strongly suggest you to angular ui bootstrap modal which gives you better controller than popover. Refer https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at modal but this disables other parts of the page. Is not a good solution...

Comment: Not angularish solution but jquery will do the job `$(element).on('click', '#cancel', function() {
            console.log("click");
        });`